# How to include files so that the project works over multiple development environments

Tags: php

I am building my first website in PHP. I am testing it locally and have two computers I am developing it on, my home computer and my Uni computer, with the main project stored in Dropbox.

The project has different root paths on both computers as they have different user names.

'/home/vadar/Dropbox/ENELWebsite/public_html/'

'/home/tcpb1/Dropbox/ENELWebsite/public_html/'

This obviously has become a problem as including files using the root path will result in an error on one computer.

I originally tried include this at my index pages, but it also requires a root path for the include file containing it, which I would have to change between computers.

```
$dir_home = '/home/vadar/Dropbox/ENELWebsite/public_html/';
$dir_uni = '/home/tcpb1/Dropbox/ENELWebsite/public_html/';
if(file_exists($dir_home) OR is_dir($dir_home)){
    define('APP_DIR', $dir_home); //home comp
}
elseif(file_exists($dir_uni) OR is_dir($dir_uni)){
    define('APP_DIR', $dir_uni); //uni comp
}
else{
    echo 'No include directory exists';
}
```

What is the smartest way to solve this problem? I realise I could just make a new user folder on either one of them, and move the Dropbox folder into it, but I am sure there is a smarter way to include files in the project itself.

Comment: Look at [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/) and if you're using or uninvested in your application framework, seriously consider [Symfony](http://symfony.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) to find the root folder.

```
$dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; // will return /home/vadar/Dropbox/ENELWebsite/public_html/
if(file_exists($dir)){ //just to make sure
    define('APP_DIR', $dir); //home comp
}
else{
    echo 'No include directory exists';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
define('APP_DIR', dirname(__DIR__));     
ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path') . PATH_SEPARATOR . APP_DIR);
```

This will insert the current directory in your include path. Now your include path will always have your current directory regardless of your environment.

In this case you are not relying on `$_SERVER`, as it can be manipulated by the client.